# What am I doing wrong in this subdomain redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I need is as follows:
People visiting 201101.donateaday.net should be sent to  http://donateaday.net/2011/01/bla-kors-norge/

I tried:
`Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^201101.donateaday.net/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://donateaday.net/2011/01/bla-kors-norge/ [r=301,l]`

However, this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Evert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your RewriteCond has some characters too many. Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 201101\.donateaday\.net
```

The dots are escaped so that they match literal dots, instead of any character.